# Ubuntu 16.04 Login Loop after changing PATH

Tags: command-line, login, .profile

I've changed my .profile file and added to the end:

```
Export PATH = "bin/somepathToMatLab"
```

This resulted after a restart, that when I login with the GUI it loops right back to the login page. I then logged in with CTRL-ALT-F1 and landed in my home directory but was unable to use "vi" to open or "cp" to copy anything because of the change to the top mentioned path.

Please help me to reset the .profile .

Answer (score 2):

```
/usr/bin/vi .profile
```

Replace

```
Export PATH = "bin/somepathToMatLab"
```

With

```
export PATH=$PATH:"bin/somepathToMatLab"
```

Comment: When i try to use "sudo vi .profile" it says : "The command could not be found, because 》/usr/bin《 is not part of the environment variable PATH. sudo: Comand not found."

Comment: @Kokonut did you try the command `/usr/bin/vi .profile` exactly as posted? there should be no need to use `sudo` to edit your own files such as `.profile` in your own home directory

Answer (score 1):

Do

```
export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
```

and change the line in your .profile file to

```
export PATH=$PATH:/bin/somepathToMatLab
```

Then logout and login again.

Comment: When i try to use "sudo vi .profile" it says : "The command could not be found, because 》/usr/bin《 is not part of the environment variable PATH. sudo: Comand not found."

Answer (score 0):

It should have been:

```
export PATH="$PATH:bin/somepathToMatLab"
```

otherwise it resets the initial PATH variable and the system can't find any of your programmes.

<strike>PS: to edit log in as root</strike>

Comment: root is normally disabled in Ubuntu. The correct way is to use `sudo vi .profile`

Comment: True, sorry! I like to re-enable it.

Comment: When i try to use "sudo vi .profile" it says : "The command could not be found, because 》/usr/bin《 is not part of the environment variable PATH. sudo: Comand not found."

Comment: as the people above suggested, use `/usr/bin/vi` for `vi` and `/usr/bin/sudo` for `sudo`

Comment: so `/usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/vi .profile`